# Appending the icon on the top of the image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am tying to append image on another image, but it doesnt work.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.step-wrapper img', function() {      
    $(this).resizable();
    $(".ui-wrapper").draggable();  
    $(this).find(".ui-wrapper").append('<i class="icon-sort-up"></i>');
    $(".icon-sort-up").css("position", "absolute")
});
```

Comment: Try to set an higher zIndex, like .css('z-index', 100); can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: does the ui-wrapper element has the 'position:relative' css style?

Comment: ui-wrapper has position: relative; the image has position: static

Comment: `$(this)` is still the `img` element the mousedown event occurred on, I presume – how do you want to `.find(".ui-wrapper")` on that? An image has no descendant elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .ui-wrapper is not a descendant of $(this), but parent, so use parent() instead of find().
The < I > is appended on outside of div.ui-wrapper and it's overflow property is hidden, so you have to set top position of icon.

It would be better to move resizable and draggable functions to document.ready because the functions create div each time when you click the img.

Here is [**my example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ncvL/1/). I replaced < i > with < img >

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.step-wrapper img').resizable();
    $(".ui-wrapper").draggable().append('<img class="icon-sort-up" src="http://thesimpsonplace.e-monsite.com/medias/album/images/76278889donut-1-jpg.jpg"/>');  
});

$(document).on('mousedown', '.step-wrapper img.homer', function(){
    $(".icon-sort-up").css("z-index",1);
});
```

css:

```
img.homer{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
}
img.icon-sort-up{
    width:15%;
    height:15%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="step-wrapper">
<img class="homer" src="http://www.boston.com/business/ticker/homer616.jpg"/>
</div>
```